# Save Object after Animation

Tags: animation, three.js

Let's say I have dummy character model. This character is *standing*. Also there is animation that make this character *sit*. When I save character to `obj` and import it into another software (eg. blender) I get *standing* model. What I want is to get *sitting* character (in blender). Is this even possible to save object in after-animation state?

I have very little experience in three.js and 3d-modeling concepts, will appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

the first thing you need to do is `obj.UpdateMatrixWorld()`. If this alone doesnt solve the problem, you probably have to clone the vertices and apply the matrix of the object to it.

```
var vector = obj.geometry.vertices[i].clone();
    vector.applyMatrix4( obj.matrixWorld );
```

And `vector` you write to the obj file as vertex. As far as i know this shouldnt affect faces or texture coords

Comment: thanks for answer, but unfortunately  obj.UpdateMatrixWorld() changed nothing. Applying matrixWorld only rotates model and that's it